# Websocket connection - "2000 All transports failed" after migrating to Vite from create-react-app. React, Sockjs-client, webstomp-client, Spring Boot

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, websocket, create-react-app, vite

I am using React in combination with the sockjs-client and webstomp-client dependencies to establish a connection with a WebSocket. Previously, I have used Create React App for initiating React projects, and the following code successfully connected to the WebSocket server:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const socket = new SockJS('https://my-service/api');

        const stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

        stompClient.connect(
            {
                'X-Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            },
            function () {
                stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/result', function (message: any) {
                    const weMessageBody = JSON.parse(message?.body);
                    // DO something with message body
                });

                stompClient.send('/app/init');
            },
            function () {
                toast.error('WS connection lost');
                socket.close();
                stompClient.disconnect();
            }
        );

    }, []);
```

Previously, when inspecting the browser's Network tab, I could observe a successful call to my backend service with a 101 code. The RequestURL indicated wss://my-service/api, and the headers included Host: my-service. On the backend, I am using Spring Boot.

However, I recently **migrated my frontend projects from Create React App to Vite**, and encountered issues. Neither WebSocket connection is successful, and I receive the message "2000 All transports failed." When running the project locally, I noticed that the call is initiated to ws://localhost:5137 (the local address of my frontend project) instead of the specified URL in the SockJS connection (https://my-service/api).

The current WebSocket request appears as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjKPj.png)

In contrast, the previous request looked like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzgKy.png)

Call never gets to the backend endpoint. It seems that the behavior has changed in the sockjs-client dependency (without a version change). It no longer automatically transitions from the initial HTTPS request (https://my-service/api) to the WebSocket protocol (wss://my-service/api/). Additionally, it lacks a part of the automatically generated sessionId appended to its WebSocket requestURL.

I haven't encountered any other errors besides the standard console logs about the WebSocket's connection status ("Disconnected from https://my-service/api"). This has been perplexing me for a few days, and I'm struggling to identify and resolve the issue. I attempted to start a plain Vite project with a basic Express.js connection to WebSocket, and it still fails. Everything works fine with the previous Create React App build and with projects that haven't been migrated to Vite yet.

Has anyone encountered the same problem or do you have any idea what seems to be a problem? I would appreciate your help.